# Can i store a List<dynamic> with shared preference

Tags: dart, flutter

I will like to store a list of values from an API locally. Does shared preference allow storing List because each time i try to save my values in shared preference, i get " type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'"

```
Future fetchAllProduct() async{
     try{
        for(int j = 1; j < 3; j++){
      final response = await 
  http.get('https://website/api/?page=1', 
     );
    List result = json.decode(response.body);
    products.addAll(result);

    //Saving fetched product list
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setStringList('prds', products);

    //final prds = preferences.getStringList('prd');
    }
  }catch (ex){
    print('$ex');
  }
  print(products);

}
```

I'am expecting to see a list like this 
[{ProductID: 155, Name: Multi-vit, Description: Multi-vit, CostPrice: 0.0, SalePrice: 80, EatOutPrice: 80, CategoryID: 976, Barcode: , TaxRateID: null, }]

Answer (score 0):

According to shared_preference's [repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/example/test/shared_preferences.dart) it should be possible to store a List. Their test case have a slightly different syntax than yours: 
`preferences.setStringList('List', kTestValues2['flutter.List'])` which is different from your approach.

I assume you have defined `products` as a List.

EDIT:
Why are you storing a list inside a list? What happens if you make your result a String?

Answer (score -1):

An easy way would be to encode the `List` as a JSON and save that as a string.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show json;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void setList(String key, List<dynamic> value) async {
  await setString(key, json.encode(value));
}


setList('key', []);
```